# Why is there a little fluctuation when the electricity connects or disconnects?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electromagnetic-induction

When the electricity connects (or disconnects), if you look at a light bulb,it would first get on (off), then off (on) and finally get on (off).
What is the reason for this?
I heard that it is because of the lenz law but i þhink it is not correct.

Comment: I don't see visible fluctuations. It's the (poor?) construction or condition of your local power grid, building wiring, or light bulb (by the way, are you asking about incandescent or fluorescent?) . Nothing so physicsy and universal as Lenz's law and more practical things like corroded contacts, contact bounce, or voltage sag.

Comment: "When electricity connects" is a bit broad and somewhat vague.  Do you mean when you flip the switch to turn the light on?

Comment: @J.Murray: I mean, for example, you are at home and suddenly the electricity goes off in your home and all others home in your neighberhood.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit vague, however here is a possible explanation:

There are at least three sorts of light bulbs:

1. The oldest models with an incandescent filament.
2. The early economical bulbs which are discharge lamps in disguise (with a discharge tube coiled inside a bulb).
3. The current power saving bulbs using semiconductor diodes to produce light (i.e. LED-based).

The ones with discharge tubes suffer the same delays as ordinary discharge tubes: they need a transformer and a capacity to supply them with the high tension they need (to generate a sustained discharge in a gas). This is basically a R.L.C circuit with a associated delay.

The ones using LEDs also require a voltage transformation stage (« driver »: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LED_circuit), for the opposite reason, they usually require low dc voltage to operate.